# WordPress hiding IMG

Tags: html, css, wordpress, jetpack

Every time I link to an image or upload via the Media page

```
style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 300px 250px;" width="0" height="0"
```

is added to the img tag. See below.

```
<img src="https://media.go2speed.org/..." style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 300px 250px;" width="0" height="0">
```

I am using a standard WordPress install on JustHost. I have JetPack installed, and deactivated Photon. This obviously hasn't fixed the problem. I also deactivated hot-linking.

The problem is that the images are being hidden by default. I want them to be visible without...

```
style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 300px 250px;" width="0" height="0"
```

...being added automatically.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: you need hide one image ? then add visibility: hidden;

Comment: I would like the images to not be hidden by default.

Comment: Give us more info here. What is the image inside a post or a featured image, or some custom field image ? Show us the php code for this part. Do you have some kind of plugins activated. (related to the images)

Comment: The images are displaying on my phone, but not on my laptop. I have the JetPack, Kento Ads Rotator, MOJO Marketplace, and WordPress SEO (Joost de Valk) plugins. The image is being inserted in a post and on the sidebar. The post images are being inserted via the img tag button. The sidebar images are being linked with img tags. I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary. This is occurring on it's own. Standard HTML. When the page is processed on my laptop, the CSS I posted is automatically added to the img tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you use Firefox with AdBlock Plus Extension in your browser? If yes, try to disable it and try again. I think that is the problem

Comment: It happens with simple social icons (with no tracking involved whatsoever and even without links) according to their name. A simple "Facebook.png" or "Linkedin.png" gets blocked by AdBlock.